# Usage of @Valid vs @Validated in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

Thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring), I think I understand how validation is working.

As for JPA, here we have a specification called JSR-303 explaining how Bean Validation should work and then we are using implementations like the commonly used Hibernate Validator or Apache BVal also.

I am struggling about using `@Valid`in some part of my code. I am not using `@Validated` because I do not need group validation.

You can find an example of a demo project [here](https://github.com/MadJlzz/multi-configuration-properties)

In `PropertyExample` class, you can see I marked my class for bean validation to happen.

When using `@Validated`, everything work as expected since I am violating a constraint in my `application.yml` file.
When using `@Valid` over `@Validated`, it seems nothing happens. I do not understand why.

I saw too that those annotations could be used on `ElementType.PARAMETER` but when I am using using them during constructor initialisation, validation doesn't seem to trigger either.

Explanations on how to used those annotations (especially the `@Valid`) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need `@Validated` to be placed on the type (class) per [Spring Boot documentation] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-validation) in order to have validation to be triggered on its methods that are annotated with, say, `@Valid` or `@Null`. I still haven't figured out why, as `@Validated` only adds *group validation* to the mix. Perhaps this post explains a bit further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426570/2187022

Answer (score 2):

It works when using Validated and doesn't when using Valid simply because Spring Boot requires properties classes to be annotated with Validated if you want them to be validated. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation):

> Spring Boot attempts to validate @ConfigurationProperties classes whenever they are annotated with Spring’s @Validated annotation
>
> [...]
>
> You can also trigger validation by annotating the @Bean method that creates the configuration properties with @Validated.

Note that they can't possibly allow the use of Valid on properties classes, since the Valid annotation isn't applicable to classes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but when are we using `@Valid` then ? Is there any use case ?

Comment: The tell the validator that a field must be validated, too. Or to validate MVC method parameters. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html

Comment: Ok so it behaves like a marker then. Much more clearer now thanks.

Comment: Note that they can't possibly allow the use of Valid on properties classes, since the Valid annotation isn't applicable to classes.