# Relation between @Valid & @Validated for a @PathVariable validation using @Min

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

Thanks to ([Usage of @Valid vs @Validated in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817075/usage-of-valid-vs-validated-in-spring)) and [Difference between @Valid and @Validated in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173332/difference-between-valid-and-validated-in-spring). I now understand the difference between them.

However,  I am unable to understand a particular scenario.

I have an Integer `@PathVariable` that I receive in a controller endpoint that I'd like to validate using `JSR-303` bean validation (I'd only be using `@Min(1)`) to ensure I get an integer `>=1` or validation fails.

**Confusion-** The setting doesn't work until I put `@Validated` on controller class, Tried `@Valid` but that didnt work. Just trying to figure out why is it required ?
When I validate a pojo with annotation @Valid I am not forced to use `@Validated` on class.
I saw in Spring docs for `@Validated` , it quotes

> Variant of JSR-303's javax.validation.Valid, supporting the specification of validation groups. Designed for convenient use with Spring's JSR-303 support but not JSR-303 specific.

But I am unable to establish relation between `@Min` and class level `@Validated` annotation.
Any help would be hugely appreciated , also excuse me if I have been unable to raise my question clearly. Any edits or suggestions are welcome.

Below is my example-

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class PrimeController {

...

@GetMapping("/is-prime/{number}")
    public ObjectNode checkPrime( @Min(1) @PathVariable Integer number) {
        return primeHandler.getPrimalityResult(number);
    }
```

Comment: `@Valid` on a `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody` is handled by the `DispatcherServlet` (or actually more accurate the Spring MVC `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which has this build in). When adding plain javax.validation annotations to method arguments (regardless if this is a controller or not) you must annotate this class with `@Validatied` so that using AOP the `MethodValidationInterceptor` can be applied. They are different mechanism to do validation.

Comment: Thank you so much @M.Deinum, It's more clearer now. Is there any way to understand this in little more detail ? how exactly spring internally does all this ?
Thanks for your comment , i was never gonna be able to establish this relation specially about "MethodValidationInterceptor" myself.

Comment: The `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` checks if a method argument is annotated with `@Valid(ated)` and will call the configured validator. To be more precise this ishandled by the `MethodArgumentResolver` responsible for `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I am happy to accept it as an answer if you put it in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Valid` on a `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody` is handled by the `DispatcherServlet` (or actually more accurate the Spring MVC `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which ultimately delegates this to the [`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java#L168) or [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java#L137) which has this build in).

When adding plain `javax.validation` annotations to method arguments (regardless if this is a controller or not) you must annotate this class with `@Validatied` so that using AOP the `MethodValidationInterceptor` [can be applied](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method). They are a different mechanism for applying validation.